# How to solve Invalid Binary error in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

A few months back I uploaded my iPhone app on the app store. Now I wish to add a new version. I didn't have the last profile or certificate. So I created a new one. Followed all the necessary steps, yet it says Invalid Binary. I am working on a deadline, and it's really important to solve this issue. Please help. I have followed many forums, questions, and answers but no luck.

Comment: Invalid Binary can have many reasons.. for example a wrong entry in the info.plist

Comment: i have cross checked it a lot of times. The profile which i used for the last version, was accidentally deleted from provisioning portal. So i cant renew it. Can that be the reason?...i had to create a new profile with same app id.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand right you lost the original developer certificate (the one that Apple say "keep this safe or you're lost") and create a new one from scratch.
Doing this you create a complete new "identity" (I mean, not a copy of the original one) so you can't upload the app as an upgrade of the older.

But if you still have somewhere the .p12 file you can re-install the private/public keys and download the old certificate of the app and this should works.

Comment: I also dont have the last profile which i used on the provisioning portal. Can i create a new profile and update a new version.

Comment: Never try honestly, but I think no, 'cause the whole certificates stuff is about security and not allowing things like that... I suggest you to contact support on Apple Dev Forum trying to keep in touch with Apple people that can maybe fix it.